# View does not flex the height in Android but works properly in iOS React native project

Tags: react-native

I am using this library: https://github.com/moschan/react-native-simple-radio-button

Issue is View is not expanding the height as per the text size.
It is working properly in iOS but Android text is not wrapping.
Please help

```
radio_props={
              let label = (
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>
                      'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                    <View style={somestyle}>
                      <Text style={styles.SomeStyle}>Testing</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
              );
              return {
                label,
                value: someValue,
                disabled: false,
              };
            },
          )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the docs of radio library it says that `radio_props` should be an `Array` and you return and `object` try to return like this

```
return[{
  label,
 ...otherKeys
  }]
```

and you are using `label` as `component`, but it should be string,
instead use `labelStyle`  and  `labelWrapStyle` to achieve what you want.